# Search file path in "Go to file" a-la Notepad++ FileSwitcher

Tags: visual-studio-code

In VSCode when searching for an open file with Ctrl-P or Go->Go to file, the search is limited to filename only. In Notepad++ the extension File Switcher has an option to include file path in the search. Is there an option/plugin in VSCode to do that?

*Update after the discussion in comments:* it's possible to look by dirname, but I would have to type it from its start. The required option/plugin would allow searching by any part of the path, the equivalent of /xyz/.test(path) on all open/recent filenames.

Comment: You can enter a file path, like "src\js" or "src/js".   Or "src/js/main.js".  It accomplishes that via fuzzy searching.  It works qu8te well actually.

Comment: Tried that and it didn't work, but somehow you made me try with a leading slash and that seems to work. So /xyz/index seems to be the way to go.

Comment: Tried  more and /xyz/index is half-way there. In NP++ it's simple filtering so searching for xyz will show both /abcxyz and /xyz whereas in vscode it won't, I have to type the correct directory name from its beginning. Am I right to assume this is the best that can be done?

Comment: Are you on v1.24.1?  Because I don't see that behavior at all.  Do you see folder names after each filename when you open Ctrl-P?  It can fuzzy search through those as well as the filename.  For me, starting with a slash is not helpful.

Comment: Was on v1.23 but just upgraded and it changed nothing. Here's what I see for "cluster": https://snag.gy/qK5FZr.jpg, and here's what I see for "/kacey-cluster/index": https://snag.gy/AQwb0x.jpg

Comment: Okay, that is expected behavior.  In your first example, if you had files in the cluster folder that did not have cluster in the filename it would find those, but they would be ordered after any filenames with cluster in them.  It will list the filename matches first but folder name-only matches will be after.  In the second example, if you just type "kacey" it would find that folder, but again since the search uses fuzzy searching it would first list any filename or foldername  with "k a c e y" in some order first.

Comment: The slash you are using only limits the search (as it  adds a character) but is not necessary for finding directories.

Comment: ok but why I don't see kacey-cluster/index anywhere (first or last) when searching for cluster? This is what I'm trying to achieve and it doesn't seem to have to take a small embedded bing to accomplish that :)

Comment: many of the modules I'm working on fit into their index.js and I need to jump between them using their dir name, this is the practice in notepad++. otherwise it becomes tedious when reaching over a hundred times per day.